# Binding a php variable with Jquery slider

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have two JQuery sliders, value of "Second_Slider" gets updated and a div named
"amount2" as well as it should.

Now i want to update an php variable to the value of "Second_Slider" also. how can i achieve this?

```
 $( "#Slider" ).bind( "slide", function(event, ui) { 
     $("#Second_Slider").slider({ value:300 });
     $( "#amount2" ).val( "$" + $( "#Second_Slider" ).slider( "value" ) );

     <?php $Php_Var_I_Want_to_Change = "what-do-i-put-here? ?> };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**updated**
you could try something like this

```
var slideXHR;

function setSlideSession(slideValue){
     if( slideXHR == 'XMLHttpRequest'){
         //stop previous ajax request
         slideXHR.abort();            
     }     
     slideXHR = $.get('url/file.php', { item : slideValue });
}

 $( "#Slider" ).bind( "slidestop", function(event, ui) { 
     $("#Second_Slider").slider({ value:300 });

     var slideValue = $( "#Second_Slider" ).slider( "value" );
     $( "#amount2" ).val( "$" + slideValue );

    //set session variable on php via ajax 
    setSlideSession( slideValue );    
};
```

php file

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['variable'] = $_GET['item']; 
?>
```

Comment: just what i was looking for. Thank you Paul

Comment: @Tom be aware you will be sending a lot of requests by doing this. If this is indeed what you need, I'd suggest putting some sort of timeout.

Comment: @Jacob i'm aware of that, could cause a DoS attack by mistake, thanks for the warning. I'm looking to the "stop" function JQuery has to offer at this moment, seems to solve this.

Comment: @Tom I made some improvements, used slidestop and it kills redundant ajax requests.

Answer (score 1):

You can't "bind" php variables to javascript variables.

Javascript is run client side, the only way you can get the values into PHP is by making a request from the client side.

e.g.

- Submitting a form
- Clicking a link
- Sending an ajax request

I wouldn't suggest an approach to take without understanding why you want to bind it in the first place.

Comment: i want to change a session variable

Answer (score 0):

I can't really get your question but if i am following right you want to update a PHP variable through a jQuery slider's `slide`event?
That's absolutely impossible once php is processed on server-side and then passed into the client as javascripts are processed on the client, after PHP has done its job!
If you want to send data to the server, use AJAX!

Answer (score 0):

you are mixing JavaScript (client-site) with PHP (server-site) - will not work.

in your case you may consider sending an ajax request on change of slider - what could be overkill - every thing depends what it is for